# Java Web service Unable to deploy typemappinp error

Tags: java, web-services, web, apache-axis

This is really frustrating and I cant figure out what is wrong.

I have created a Class `MyClass`, it contains a few attributes (Strings only) and a method called `get_MyClass` which returns a `MyClass` object. When I try to create a Java Web Service, it gives me the following error:

> SEVERE: Unable to deploy typemapping: {MYNAMESPACE}MyClass
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MYNAMESPACE.MyClass_Type    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)

The thing is that if I delete the `get_MyClass` function the Web Service works fine and doesn't give me any errors. Why can't my Web Service output a custom class? I am using eclipse btw

CODE SAMPLE:

```
public class MyClass{
public String a;
public String b;
public int c;
public String v;

public MyClass getMyClass()
{
    MyClass d = new MyClass();
    return d;

}

//Plus gets and sets


}
```

Comment: I recommend you show some code, e.g. MyClass...

Comment: Are the `MyClass` class and the web service class at the same project? (Same JAR?)

Comment: Well, MyClass is in one project with the WDSL, but it is used by a client (which has all the servicelocator, proxy, etc. classes) in another project